# Why postgres can use configuration file not in its own home directory?

Tags: users, configuration

`debian` is the normal account in my os:

```
debian@debian:~$ cat /etc/passwd  |grep  debian
debian:x:1000:1000:debian,,,:/home/debian:/bin/bash
```

The home directory for `postgres` is `/var/lib/postgresql`:

```
debian@debian:~$ cat /etc/passwd  |grep  postgres
postgres:x:117:129:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

No `.psqlrc` or `psqlrc` file in `/var/lib/postgresql`,i have write a configuration file in `/home/debian/.psqlrc`.

I found that if i enter into shell with account `postgres`

```
sudo -i -u  postgres
```

Why setting on `/home/debian/.psqlrc` (not postgres' home directory) can be called by user `postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

`.psqlrc` is for the `psql` command, which is a Postgres database *client*. Any user on the system (or on any other system) can use such a client; the database may or may not be configured to accept incoming connections from different hosts and users.

For service accounts like your `postgres` the home directory can have less meaning than for user accounts intended for regular human logins. For PostgreSQL specifically, the home directory of the `postgres` user might be also used as the default location of the database, or it might just exist so that there is a default location for core dumps of the PostgreSQL database engine in case it crashes, or that cron jobs running as `postgres` can have a place to drop their `dead.letter` file if cron job results cannot be mailed for some reason.

If `/home/debian/.psqlrc` is readable to the `postgres` user and there is a line like

```
PSQLRC=/home/debian/.psqlrc
```

in the `~/.bashrc` of the `postgres` user, then the `psql` command would use the same configuration file when invoked as either `debian` or `postgres` user. This might be convenient if regular database administration would be expected to be done using the `debian` account, but major DB maintenance or restore operations might still require the database admin to log in as `postgres` in rare occasions.

Comment: No line PSQLRC=/home/debian/.psqlrc  in `.bashrc`.